# Android AlertDialog divider not showing everywhere

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, divider

I'm displaying a simple DialogFragment with an AlertDialog and a simple list.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      builder.setItems(times, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
      });
      builder.setTitle("Select an end date");
      AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
      ListView listView = alertDialog.getListView();
      listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
      listView.setDividerHeight(1);
      return alertDialog;
    }
  }
```

But as you can see on the picture bellow, not all the diver are black ??
Could someone help me to get normal divider between the items ?
[image]

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked fine for me: http://imgur.com/XGokQCP    Note that I used `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;`

Comment: This is curious. Also I notice that the title in your is bigger than mine. Is there anything in the them that can cause my problem?

Comment: The large title is probably just a result of the screen size, I tested on a Nexus 6. Is times just a String array?  Check all of your themes and styles, that could be the source of how it's displaying.

Comment: yes the time is a simple string. I'm testing this on the emulator Nexus 6, API 23. Have just tested on my actual Samsung s6 and the divider are all here, but the title.. is still small compared to yours

Comment: Are you using window scaling on the emulator?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I have created the emulator normally with specifying any scaling factor